# Is it possible to create a value-type struct in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, clone

Probably been asked before but I'm creating a mathematical `Vector` type which looks like this:

```
class Vec2 {  
  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
  }

  magnitude(): number {
    return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y);
  }

  // etc
}
```

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
let v1 = new Vec2(5, 5);
let v2 = v1; // this currently copies by reference instead of by value
v2.x = 10; // as a result v1.x is now also 10, whereas I want it to stay 5
```

Can this be done? I know I could make an explicit `copy` function, but I'd prefer to just make sure equals worked, so that I never accidentally modify an existing vector if I forget to call `copy`.

Comment: No, you cannot make that work without an explicit clone function.

Comment: Unfortunate. Alright, thanks.